# HTML formatted text in UIWebView shows a bar after the formatted text

Tags: html, ios, css

This is the HTML formatted text I'm sending to a UIWebView instance.

```
"This is my sample
<br>
question text." And
<br>
<a style="padding:2px; font-family:'Futura-CondensedExtraBold',Georgia,Serif; color:white; border:0px solid;border-radius:10px; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(102,184,24) 4%, rgb(197,228,71) 52%); ">"The sample</a>
<a style="padding:2px; font-family:'Futura-CondensedExtraBold',Georgia,Serif; color:white; border:0px solid;border-radius:10px; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(102,184,24) 4%, rgb(197,228,71) 52%); ">
<br>
<a style="padding:2px; font-family:'Futura-CondensedExtraBold',Georgia,Serif; color:white; border:0px solid;border-radius:10px; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(102,184,24) 4%, rgb(197,228,71) 52%); ">answer text goes</a>
<a style="padding:2px; font-family:'Futura-CondensedExtraBold',Georgia,Serif; color:white; border:0px solid;border-radius:10px; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(102,184,24) 4%, rgb(197,228,71) 52%); ">
<br>
<a style="padding:2px; font-family:'Futura-CondensedExtraBold',Georgia,Serif; color:white; border:0px solid;border-radius:10px; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(102,184,24) 4%, rgb(197,228,71) 52%); ">here"</a>.
```

And here is the image of an output in the UIWebView.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mQWPs/)

[image]

I'm seing a same color vertical bar next to each formatted line in the webview.

I highly appreciate any tips/advices on this. Thanks.

Comment: Check my **Updated** answer with the demo.

Comment: For future reference, you would *greatly* benefit from defining this in a CSS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your code has 2 `<a>` which does not contain any text and even it has no `</a>` end tag (*syntax error*). And you have given `style="padding:2px"` to them. So it will pad 2px inside `<a>` tag and will show background color.

Remove that 2 `<a>` and it will work as you want.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BpEzZ/)

Comment: Thanks you for the quick input! I totally didn't see that and the text was being created programmatically.

Comment: @KoolestM - My pleasure.and so you will need to check this code is being generated. :)